# Shorter way to conditionally "return ()" in a monad chain (>>, >>=) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have this simple code which reads a string and prints it, indefinitely.

```
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= putStrLn >> main
```

Now I want to exit after the `getLine` call if the line is either "quit" or "exit".

My attempt:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  line <- getLine
  if line == "exit" || line == "quit"
  then return ()
  else putStrLn line >> main
```

Doesn't look idiomatic to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: You could try `when` in `Control.Monad`

Comment: `main = interact $ unlines . takeWhile (/= "exit") . lines`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Control.Monad.unless` (and it's slightly more popular cousin, `when`) abstract this pattern out of your code:

```
import Control.Monad (unless)

main = do
  line <- getLine
  unless (line == "exit" || line == "quit") $ do
    putStrLn line
    main
  -- or
  when (line /= "exit" && line /= "quit") $ do
    putStrLn line
    main
```

A conditional `return ()` followed by unconditional code won't do the trick, as `return` is just a function, not a flow control keyword as in most other languages.

Answer (score 9):

Using `pipes-4.0`:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $
    P.stdinLn >-> P.takeWhile (`notElem` ["quit", "exit"]) >-> P.stdoutLn
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to flip a function without using `flip`!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are concerned about the *sequential feel* of the code because of using if/else and the do notation. You can try something like:

```
main = getLine >>= proc
  where
    proc s | s == "exit" || s == "quit" = return ()
           | otherwise = putStrLn s >> main
```

Answer (score 3):

An attempt to be fashionable:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import System.IO

isValid s = s ≠ "quit" && s ≠ "exit"

getL ∷ MaybeT IO String
getL = do s ← lift getLine
          guard (isValid s)
          return s


main = runMaybeT main' where
  main' = do
      lift $ putStr "Enter line: "
      lift $ hFlush stdout
      s ← getL
      lift $ putStrLn $  "Your line is: " ⧺ s
      main'
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create a helper function that repeats a given action while it returns value:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

while :: (Monad m) => MaybeT m b -> m ()
while k = runMaybeT (forever k) >> return ()
```

Once `k` returns `mzero`, the loop stops. Then we can use it nicely to interrupt the loop at any place using the standard `MonadPlus` combinators:

```
main = while $ do
        l <- lift getLine
        guard $ l /= "quit"
        lift $ putStrLn l
```

Or on one line:

```
main = while $ mfilter (/= "quit") (lift getLine) >>= lift . putStrLn
```

---

**Update:** Perhaps the simplest solutions is using [`whileJust_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v%3awhileJust_) from *monad-loops*:

```
isValid s | s /= "quit"   = Just s
          | otherwise     = Nothing

main = whileJust_ (isValid `liftM` getLine) putStrLn
```